# Skew symmetric product under positive definite transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have two matrices $V^T, U$ such that their product is skew-symmetric: $V^TU = -U^T V$.
If the matrix $A$ is symmetric positive definite, can anything be said about the product $V^T A^T A U$?

Comment: What is your initial guess? What have you tried? Have you tried with some small examples?

Comment: All I can say is that $\det(V^TA^2U)$ is nonnegative. If it were $UA^2V^T$, however, I can say more: its eigenvalues are purely imaginary.